# what is more memory intensive in Unity: 100 GameObjects with PaticleSystems, or 100 GameObjects spawning other GOs

Tags: unity, memory-efficiency

I am making a bullet hell game. Say there are 100 bullets on the screen, and each bullet has a trail effect. Is it more performant to give each GameObject a ParticleSystem, or for each GameObject, instance child particle GameObjects? I am developing the game in Unity.

Comment: Questions of the form "Do I get better performance with X or Y" are best answered by trying it and measuring the results. That way you're sure you're getting the answer that's right for your project, under your load conditions, running on your target hardware, etc. Not an answer based on hearsay, an older engine version, different load assumptions, etc., as you're at risk of getting when you delegate this kind of question to strangers on the Internet.

Comment: However, it's worth keeping in mind that 1) particle systems are specifically optimized for bulk updates and rendering, unlike regular game objects, and 2) you don't need a separate particle system for every bullet - you could have a system for each bullet type, which spawns particles in multiple places, tracking each bullet of its type.

Comment: Have you considered using [Entities](https://unity.com/dots)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particles are much more lightweight than full-fledged game objects. So using the standard particle system (or even better: [visual effects graph](https://unity.com/visual-effect-graph)) will likely get better results than trying to build your own particle system based on game objects.

However, if you want to use particle systems in a way which is not just cosmetic but actually affects the game mechanically, then you are trying to fit a square peg in a round hole, and will pay the performance tax for that.

So while it might be feasible to make each bullet a game object with an attached particle system, it might not be such a good idea to try to make the bullets themselves particles.

And by the way, if you want to create a game with a large number of relatively simple objects, then that might be a perfect use-case for [the new Entity - Component - System architecture of Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.9/manual/index.html). The whole feature is still not really production-quality, so dealing with it can be rather frustrating at times. But if you are brave enough to handle it, it can give you amazing performance.